# pass data between child to parent page without refresh parent page

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have one video library website, on which I have to add  one popup page which contain video list, now on that list if user click on any video, that video data should pass to parent video and play it, but Main requirement is parent page should not refresh.

I need something like,

> (for example) on popup page user click on some button, let say Video001
>   and on parent page it shows :  "You clicked Video001 from popup!!"

Answer (score 0):

The browsers localstore is what you are looking for, [a library like this one](http://www.jstorage.info) can help you to keep the data and on the main window you have a loop (setTimeout is your friend) that looks for new commands. All really simple to implement.